# How to write data driven tests using JUnit 3

Tags: junit3, data-driven

I want to create test cases at runtime. The testcases will be created from some excel file and depending upon the values in excel. I know we have @Parametrized in JUnit4 but I cannot use JUnit4. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "parameterized test case" was invented before JUnit 3.8.  Here's an [example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/95776/Testing/Parameterizing-test-cases).  JUnit 4 added first class support to it so you don't need to override suite() anymore.  I used the JUnit 3.8 method for a number of years before JUnit 4 existed.  It works just fine.